# Automatically Assign Default Configuration Profile to New Devices in DEP？

Tags: ios, mdm, dep, apple-business-manager

I am currently developing for the Device Enrollment Program (DEP) and have encountered a workflow challenge. Every time a new iPhone is added through the configurator, I need to manually call the API provided in the Apple Developer Documentation ([Assign a Profile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/assign_a_profile)) to assign a predefined configuration profile to the device.

This manual step is time-consuming and prone to errors. I am searching for a method or a best practice that would allow me to automatically assign new devices to a default configuration profile as soon as they are added through the configurator, thus streamlining the enrollment process.

Has anyone dealt with a similar challenge or can offer insights into achieving this automation? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.